# Realm with Apollo GraphQl API

Tags: mongodb, react-native, mongoose, realm, apollo-server

I am looking to build a React Native app and I'd like to use Realm so it can be used offline and then synced once the connection is restored. However, I'd like to use the same API I use for the web app built on NextJs, powered by a serverless (AWS Lambda) Apollo GraphQl API built using MongoDB and Mongoose. It'll be my first time using Realm and I'm wondering if I can use it with this same API. Some additional questions:

- Are there downsides to this approach?
- Would it be better to create a Realm database?
- Would that be more expensive?

When I search online all I can find are guides showing how to use Realm and Apollo Client.

Comment: The Realm Documentation fully covers setting up an Apollo Client to be used with Realm. Check it out [Apollo Client (React) - Web SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/graphql-apollo-react/)

Comment: Yes, it covers how to consume a Realm GraphQl API with Apollo Client. In my case, I have a serverless Apollo Server GraphQl API ready. I'm trying to understand how to use that API while taking advantage of Realm's offline and data syncing capabilities or if I'll have to create a Realm API instead.

Comment: You're using React, right? So that's the SDK you'd access Realm from. No?

Comment: I'm using React Native and I can use Apollo Client to consume the serverless GraphQl API I already have, built with Apollo Server. It uses a regular MongoDB database. I would like to allow users to use the app offline and then have it sync with the database once they have connection again. I read Realm is a good option for that, but I'm not sure how to proceed and use it with my current API. I'm hoping not to have to create a Realm DB separate from my existing MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing API connected with a regular MongoDB database, like in my case, you can use Atlas Device Sync. As they put it, it is "Realm in the Front, MongoDB in the Back". It creates a bridge between your existing MongoDB database and Realm. From what I understood, it kind of makes a copy of your database on Realm and the bridge makes sure both are always updated with the same data.

If you make changes to MongoDB, it'll update the Realm db that feeds the mobile app, and vice-versa.

The downside is that it is an extra cost, so if you're starting from scratch, it's probably better to create a Realm db and use that one.